# Azure availability zone for web api App service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How does Azure availability zone work? For example I have set up 3 web api as app service, I need to ensure that whenever 1 of the API was down, It will redirect to the next available service.

Ex:

Main API - Down
Secondary API - Up
Tertiary API  - Up

Expected: Calls to Main API will be redirected to next available (Secondary, or Tertiary if Secondary was also down)

Answer (score 1):

AZ support for App Services (the multi tenant offering) is actually just offered since yesterday: https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/08/25/App-service-support-for-availability-zones.html

Follow that guide how to enable it. Basically you need to run at least 3 instances in the app services plan and the platform will make sure those are spread out over different Zones.

Comment: Great feature. Do you know if SLA is higher? By default App Service has 99,95% SLA.

Comment: No didn’t see anything regarding SLA change yet. But that might still come later, given that the feature was just rolled out